# Extract rows from a data frame under certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have to filter my dataframe in relation to particular condition. 
Better if the solution contemplates the use of dplyr.

i have a dataframe structure like this

```
  sentId.   B.   label.   partner. code
    1.      2.     3.       4.      123
    1.      2.     2.       4.      124
    4.      2.     3.       8.      125
    7.      3.     2.       7.      126
```

If the column **label** contains a particular value (for example, 3.), collect not only that **Row** but also all the Rows that have the same **sentID** and **partner value** of the previous one.

The expected results is this:

```
  sentId.   B.   label.   partner. code
    1.      2.     3.       4.      123
    1.      2.     2.       4.      124
    4.      2.     3.       8.      125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to `filter` the rows after grouping by 'sentId.` and 'partner.'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(sentId., partner.) %>%
  filter(3 %in% label.)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   sentId. [2]
#  sentId.    B. label. partner.  code
#    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#1       1     2      3        4   123
#2       1     2      2        4   124
#3       4     2      3        8   125
```

---

Or in a compact way with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[3 %in% label.], .(sentId., partner.)]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
df1[with(df1, ave(label.==3, sentId., partner., FUN = any)),]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(sentId. = c(1, 1, 4, 7), B. = c(2, 2, 2, 3), label. = c(3, 
 2, 3, 2), partner. = c(4, 4, 8, 7), code = 123:126),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: It is necessary to extend the groupBy also to the "partner" value. It works in that way. Thank you

Comment: @Silvia I added `partner` also

Answer (score 1):

We can first find out the row indices where we have our interested `label` value and then use those indices to subset `sentId` and `partner` values from the entire dataframe.

```
label_value <- 3
inds <- df$label == label_value
df[with(df, sentId %in% sentId[inds] & partner %in% partner[inds]), ]

#  sentId B label partner code
#1      1 2     3       4  123
#2      1 2     2       4  124
#3      4 2     3       8  125
```

---

The same logic in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(sentId %in% sentId[label == label_value] & 
         partner %in% partner[label == label_value])
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can easily be formulated using SQL, so one option would be to use the `sqldf` library:

```
library(sqldf)

# your data frame df
sql <- "SELECT t1.\"sentId.\", t1.\"B.\", t1.\"label.\", t1.\"partner.\", t1.code
        FROM yourTable t1
        WHERE t1.\"label.\" = '3.' OR
            EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                    WHERE t1.\"sentId.\" = t2.\"sentId.\" AND
                          t1.\"partner.\" = t2.\"partner.\" AND
                          t2.\"label.\" = '3.')"

result <- sqldf(sql)
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: The above demo actually uses MariaDB, because SQLite was not working with the demo tool.  But it still shows that the query logic be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:
It extracts `sentID` and `partner` with label 3 as two inner queries and fetches the result from it.

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\.", "", names(df)) # to remove . from column name
sqldf("select * from df where (sentID IN (select sentID from df where label IS 3) OR 
      partner IN (select partner from df where label IS 3))")
```

Output:

```
  sentId B label partner code
1      1 2     3       4  123
2      1 2     2       4  124
3      4 2     3       8  125
```

Comment: Note: The actual column names have dots in them, so you would have to escape them, using the particular syntax of your underlying database engine.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks for correcting me. Removing first `.` from column name to make it easier.